# How can I retrieve a node after wrapping my Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component is defined as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HOCName from "./HOCName";
class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
export default HOCName(Hello);
```

MY HOC is defined as follows:

```js
import React from "react";

export default WrappedComponent => props => {
  const age = 23;
  return (
    <div>
      <WrappedComponent {...props} age={age} />
      <button>say Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My question is how can I retrieve my button in my Component "Hello" ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose one of the solutions

1. Pass button as a child of the passed component
2. Pass the button as a prop to the WrappedComponent

Here is an example of the two solutions
https://codesandbox.io/s/96q5ll9k4

Comment: Thank you a lot, it seems to be working fine. But how can I add an event Handler to the button ? I want to add an OnClick Event to the button

Comment: There are many ways. It depends what you want to achieve and where you want to create the `onClick` handler. You can pass it as props to HOC, you can use `render props`, you can create new component where you define the handler and you pass it to the main component from HOC. I modified my previous sandbox and create one more example https://codesandbox.io/s/3yp198omzm